# Permutation & Combination Arrangements Of Groups Of Similar Items Answer Is Not Satifactory

Tags: permutations, combinations

I was troubling in a question and i found the solution of the same question  on this website [Mathforum](https://web.archive.org/web/20171228050932/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56245.html). The Question is -

How many arrangements
of six 0's, five 1's, and four 2's are there in which

i) the first 0 precedes the first 1?
ii) the first 0 precedes the first 1, precedes the first 2?

The First solution is right I think but 2nd solution is not right I think.
Please correct me if i am wrong. I want confirmation. Following Is Given On The Website.

Arrangements of 0's, 1's, and 2's

> i) the first 0 precedes the first 1?

This is more difficult than it first appears.  We have

6 0's,   5 1's,    4 2's  =  15 digits

You must consider several non-overlapping configurations. For example,
you could have 0 followed by every possible arrangement of the
remaining digits, or 20 followed by every possible arrangement of the
remaining digits, or 220 followed etc.

$$\begin{align}&\bbox[pink,0.2ex]{\begin{array}{c:lcl} \text{First positions}& \text{Number and type of remaining digits}\\ \hdashline
      0&5\textit{ 0's}, 5\textit{ 1's}, 4\textit{ 2's}  &=& 14!/[5!5!4!] \\
     20&5\textit{ 0's}, 5\textit{ 1's}, 3\textit{ 2's}  &=& 13!/[5!5!3!] \\
    220&5\textit{ 0's}, 5\textit{ 1's}, 2\textit{ 2's}  &=& 12!/[5!5!2!] \\
   2220&5\textit{ 0's}, 5\textit{ 1's}, 1\textit{ 2}    &=& 11!/[5!5!1!] \\
  22220&5\textit{ 0's}, 5\textit{ 1's}         &=& 10!/[5!5!0!] \\
\end{array}}
\\  \text{Total} &= \frac 1{5!5!}[ \frac{14!}{4!} + \frac{13!}{3!} + \frac{12!}{2!} + \frac{11!}{1!} + \frac{10!}{0!}]
\\        &=  343980
\end{align}$$

> ii) the first 0 precedes the first 1, precedes the first 2?

This time we MUST start with 0 and thereafter simply repeat the above
calculation except that we now consider the digits 1 and 2 instead of
0 and 1.  So having started with 0, we then have

```
5 0's,   5 1's,   4 2's
```

I am now considering the arrangements of the 14 digits AFTER removing
the first 0.

$$\begin{align}&\bbox[pink,0.2ex]{\begin{array}{r:lcl} \text{First positions}& \text{Number and type of remaining digits}\\ \hdashline
   1&5\textit{ 0's}, 4\textit{ 1's}, 4\textit{ 2's} &=& 13!/[5!4!4!] \\
  01&4\textit{ 0's}, 4\textit{ 1's}, 4\textit{ 2's} &=& 12!/[4!4!4!] \\
 001&3\textit{ 0's}, 4\textit{ 1's}, 4\textit{ 2's} &=& 11!/[3!4!4!] \\
0001&2\textit{ 0's}, 4\textit{ 1's}, 4\textit{ 2's} &=& 10!/[2!4!4!] \\
   00001&1\textit{ 0},   4\textit{ 1's}, 4\textit{ 2's} &=&  9!/[1!4!4!] \\
  000001&0\textit{ 0's},  4\textit{ 1's}, 4\textit{ 2's} &=&  8!/[0!4!4!] \\
\end{array}}
\\  \text{Total} &= \frac 1{4!4!}[ \frac{13!}{5!} + \frac{12!}{4!} + \frac{11!}{3!} + \frac{10!}{2!} + \frac{9!}{1!} + \frac{8!}{0!}]
\\     &=  140140
\end{align}$$

Comment: Looks good except for formatting.

Comment: I am so sorry. I am a newbie and still figuring out that.

Comment: So, what doubts do you have about the given solution?

Comment: In the second solution the first line i.e first position starts with 1 why? Isn't it should start with 01?

Comment: The string of *15 characters* must start with "0", and what you are counting is the arrangements for the *remaining* 14 characters, such that the first "1" occurs before the first "2".

Comment: I am talking about the second question i.e the first 0 precedes the first 1, precedes the first 2? So here the first 0 comes first then 1 then 2

Comment: Yes.  The first "0" must proceed everything and *after that*, in the remaining 14 characters (5 "0", 5 "1", 4 "2"), the first "1" must precede the first "2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is $$\frac{13!}{5!4!4!}+\frac{12}{4!4!4!}+\frac{11!}{3!4!4!}+\frac{10!}{2!4!4!}+\frac{9!}{1!4!4!}+\frac{8!}{0!4!4!}$$